# Symfony2 VichUploader File Entity

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

Trying to work out how to use the VichUploader Bundle for symfony2 to upload to an existing table. I don't have an entity for this table yet, just wondering how you make my situation work with Symfony2 and the VichUploaderBundle.

I have read the docs and cannot match any code / help to my situation.

The table which stores files is called secure_file and the schema is:

- id
- user_id
- filename
- created_at
- updated_at

The entity I want to map this to in order to upload the file and store it into the database is called consultant. How can I upload a file (PDF, Images only) and have this store into another table on upload, i'm quite new to symfony so please fleash out your responses as much as time allows. The field i'm trying to map from in the consultant table is called image_id and I also need to pass through extra details to the secure_file entity in order to add the file to the secure_file table.

Alternatively if anyone knows of an easier way to do this then please point me at it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a one-to-one relationship between consultants and secure files (it would be the same with a one-to-many).
In that case, you just need to [make the secure file entity uploadable](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#usage) as described in `VichUploaderBundle` documentation. Once your entity is configured, just create a form for the consultant entity which will embed one or several secure files (using an [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) or a [collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html))

Comment: Thanks for your input K-Phoen, i've got the solution working without the mapping. I have tried to add in the mapping, but i'm failling to do this.

Your comment suggests that I should be doing the file upload through the Secure_file entity and not the Consults entity as i'm currently doing this. I'm getting the error of:

Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Consult::setImage() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Image, string given...

I know this is because this is passing a string and not the image object, does this mean I should be performing this on the secure_file entity?